# Use of Workbook and Sheet classes in Apache POI?

Tags: java, apache

I am working on a Microsoft excel sheet and I am using `Apache POI APIs` for this purpose. There are classes called `Workbook` and `Sheet`.

Can somebody please tell me what do these both classes are for? I searched it on `Apache POI` page and to be honest I didn't understand a thing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's obvious by name, Workbook refers to workbook in excel and sheet refers to individual excel sheet.

Comment: Try to run a few first examples from Apache POI busy developer's guide: i.e. http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CreateCells and see what it maps to in the generated Excel document. This should give you a better feel than any long explanation. Then just look at the available methods and consult the documentation to get the full picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do any action in excel via poi, the following must be known

1. What is the file that we are going to work on.
   This is referred to by the Workbook object
2. Which sheet we are going to work on.
   This is referred to by the Sheet object.

So, if we want to say enter a data in a cell, we need to create object reference for the workbook and then for the  sheet and then for the cell and then the data should be entered.

Answer (score 2):

Consider

> workbook

as a whole Spreadsheet that you normally have in Microsoft excel

and

> Sheet

is worksheet like sheet1,sheet2...

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface Workbook
```

High level representation of a Excel workbook. This is the first object most users will construct whether they are reading or writing a workbook. It is also the top level object for creating new sheets/etc.

All Known Implementing Classes:

```
HSSFWorkbook, SXSSFWorkbook, XSSFWorkbook
```

HSSF and XSSF provides ways to read spreadsheets create, modify, read and write XLS spreadsheets. They provide:

```
low level structures for those with special needs
an eventmodel api for efficient read-only access
a full usermodel api for creating, reading and modifying XLS files
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
public interface Sheet
extends java.lang.Iterable<Row>
```

High level representation of a Excel worksheet.

Sheets are the central structures within a workbook, and are where a user does most of his spreadsheet work. The most common type of sheet is the worksheet, which is represented as a grid of cells. Worksheet cells can contain text, numbers, dates, and formulas. Cells can also be formatted.

All Superinterfaces:

```
java.lang.Iterable<Row>
```

All Known Implementing Classes:

```
HSSFSheet, SXSSFSheet, XSSFChartSheet, XSSFDialogsheet, XSSFSheet
```

Usage:

```
// create a new file
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("workbook.xls");
// create a new workbook
Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
// create a new sheet
Sheet s = wb.createSheet();
// declare a row object reference
Row r = null;
// declare a cell object reference
Cell c = null;
```

Now you can use this cell to to your task.